# Trying to connect to twisted Server using sample code echoserver.py from twisted book. Getting error can't listen to multiple address

Tags: python, networking, twisted

Using the sample code from twisted book: echoserver.py 2-1. I keep getting this error

> line 980, in startListening
>       raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le) twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:8000:
>   [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Code:

```
 from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor


class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)


class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Any ideas on how to fix the error or why my computer is thinking that there is more than one usage on this socket address? Totally new to networking.

Comment: Do you have anything else set up on port 8000? Try some other port.

Comment: @Ivan86 how do I check that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this error then port 8000 is currently running another process if you are windows, simply open the command prompt and type

```
NETSTAT -A
```

To see which ports are already listening and which are established. Use another port that is not running anything.